# How to make the main end last?

Tags: java, multithreading

**How to make the main processs ended last?**

For example I write some code, which created one Thread: *Test*, who created another three threads - *Test2*, but main finished before *Test* started.

```
public class Test implements Runnable{
    String url;
    Thread mThread;

    public Test(String url) {
        this.url = url;        
    }

    public void start(){
       this.mThread = new Thread(this);
       this.mThread.start();
    }

     @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("TEST STARTED!");
        Test2 wclw[] = new Test2[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < wclw.length; i++) {
                wclw[i] = new Test2(url, i + 1);
                wclw[i].start();
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("MAin STARTED!");
        (new Test("qwerty")).start();

        System.out.println("MAIN FINISHED");
    }
}

class Test2 implements Runnable{
    String url;
    int threadNum;
    Thread mThread;

    public Test2(String url, int threadNum) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void start(){
        this.mThread = new Thread(this);
        this.mThread.start();
    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {
         System.out.println("TEST2 STARTED!");   
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MAin STARTED! 
MAIN FINISHED 
TEST STARTED!
qwerty
TEST2 STARTED!
TEST2 STARTED!
qwerty
qwerty 
TEST2 STARTED!
qwerty 
qwerty
qwerty
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to make the main processs ended last?

I assume you mean the main *thread*.  You need to use `thread.join()`.  Your main should join with the thread that it spawns and the sub-thread needs to join with the threads that it spawns as well.  `thread.join()` waits for the thread to finish before it continues.

```
Test test = new Test("qwerty");
// start the test thread running in the background
test.start();
// do other stuff on the main thread
...
// wait for the test thread to finish
test.mThread.join();
```

Inside the test thread you should do:

```
// start other threads
for (int i = 0; i < wclw.length; i++) {
    wclw[i] = new Test2(url, i + 1);
    wclw[i].start();
}
// do other stuff in the test thread if necessary
...
// come back and wait for them all to finish
for (int i = 0; i < wclw.length; i++) {
    wclw[i].mthread.join();
}
```

So the sub-thread will wait for each of the threads that it spawned to finish and then it will finish.  The main thread will wait for the sub-thread to finish and will then finish last.

FYI: it is not a problem to have the main thread finish before the sub-threads.  The sub-threads are not daemon threads so the JVM will wait for them to complete before the JVM shuts down.

Comment: Thank you! I understand and did what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Thread#join call to wait other thread completion:

```
System.out.println("MAin STARTED!");
Test t = new Test("qwerty");
t.start();
t.mThread.join();
System.out.println("MAIN FINISHED");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this problem with "daemon" property of your running thread.

> *[Thinking in Java - Daemon threads](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ315_005.htm)*
>
> A “daemon” thread is one that is supposed to provide a general service
> in the background as long as the program is running, but is not part
> of the essence of the program. Thus, when all of the non-daemon
> threads complete, the program is terminated. ***Conversely, if there are
> any non-daemon threads still running, the program doesn’t terminate.***

The method *Test.start* should be modified as follows:

```
public void start(){
   this.mThread = new Thread(this);
   this.mThread.setDaemon(false); // This method must be called before the thread is started.
   this.mThread.start();
}
```

Comment: @Gray - yes you're right, but I thik that wasn't the real question/problem... I think the terminating VM was the real itcher for Wild_klas. Your answer is the only valid answer to the question "How to make the main processs ended last?".